# Measure user activity time on webpage

Tags: javascript, session, newrelic

For newrelic custom monitoring, Measuring time(in sec) user spends on a page to record time in and time out. I have the timestamp when user session is created or visits the page, however need to identify time of session end solely using javascript.

Code Tried

```
window.onbeforeunload = function(event) {       
    doSomething();
    //event.returnValue = "Is this working";
    };

    function doSomething(){
            //const t = new Date();
            //const ctime = t.getTime();
            //Test
            newrelic.setCustomAttribute('ctime', "sal");
            }
```

Comment: By "time out", do you mean the time the user  closes the page or navigates to some other page?

Comment: Both.. closing the page as well as going out of focus.

Answer (score 1):

You can go for polling, where periodical poll can get you the status of active or lost session, and hence you can capture the timestamp for the same.

Also using unload method of javascript for doing an ajax call can help you as follows:

```
$(window).unload(function() {
  var end = new Date();
  $.ajax({ 
    url: "log.php",
    data: {'timeSpent': end - start},
    async: false
  })
```

});

Answer (score 1):

You can use the "**onunload**" or "**onbeforeunload**" event:

```
<body onbeforeunload="return onBeforeUnload()">
```

where onBeforeUnload() is:

```
<script>

    function onBeforeUnload() {
      // log the out time
    }

</script>
```

Comment: This event only allows you to change and set custom text and not muchmore. I read that some browsers do not even allow your custom text to be used! I have to call a function where i am setting a custom attribute. Attaching the code i tried.